# Type theory from ground up, first book recomendation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, type-theory

Basically I have a huge problem in finding a decent resource for learning type theory.

I would like you to recommend any kind of resource for learning type theory in mathematical sense.

Also I want to note that I have no prior experience with any kind of type theory(basically all I know about it is that it exists).

So bearing that in mind, where can I go from here?

Comment: "Basically I have a huge problem in finding a decent resource for learning type theory." Me too dude. Me too.

Comment: In fact this seems to be a near-universal problem...

Comment: Seems so but I cant help but wonder why is it so.Even in this time when HoTT is a hot topic

Comment: There is a [homotopy type theory book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), you know.

Comment: I know about HoTT book but I perceive it to be out of my reach at this point,Thanks anyhow

Comment: One option for "gaining access" to the HoTT book is to watch Bob Harper's lectures.  In fall 2014 he gave a graduate seminar in HoTT at CMU. In Summer 2015, he gave a condensed version at OPLSS. Links to the videos are in the [TypeFunc](https://github.com/williamdemeo/TypeFunc) list that I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You can see :

- Peter Andrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory : To Truth Through Proof](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (1986)
- J.Roger Hindley, [Basic Simple Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=XgyI7vY0BLgC&printsec=frontcover) (1997)
- Fairouz Kamareddine & Twan Laan, [A Modern Perspective on Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZIHs6Kar0vIC&pg=PR1) (2004).

---

You can see also :

- William Farmer, [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S157086830700081X/1-s2.0-S157086830700081X-main.pdf?_tid=56777100-642f-11e5-99e4-00000aacb360&acdnat=1443259198_e4658abd2e62333d93cc776ef21d331d) (2008).

Comment: +1 Andrews is insanely expensive, but if you really want to get a handle on simple type theory and it's relationship to mathematical logic, you simply must work through it. And the paper by Farmer gives a great overview once you've mastered the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have background in category theory, you might take a look at [Categorical Logic and Type Theory](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/CLT/bookinfo.html) by Bart Jacobs.

Like you I had no experience with type theory and I've been told to read it. I'm far from finishing it but so far I'm pretty satisfied.

**Edit.** Maybe it is worth saying that the book emphasizes the fact that there is not one type theory but numerous ones; basically one for each Grothendieck fibration over *nice categories*. Just the introduction and the first chapter helped me to understand the differences between simply type theory and dependent type theory for example.